# Problema com DataSet DataGridView [C#]

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview, dataset, export

Tudo bem?

Estou tendo problemas ao popular um `DataGridView`com os dados do DataSet.

No meu `button1` eu realizo a busca, leitura e importação para o `DataGriView` de todos arquivos xml de um determinado diretório. Até aí funciona normal, os dados são exibidos no `DataGridView`.

```
  DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            string[] array2 = Directory.GetFiles("temPFiles", "*.xml");


            foreach (string name in array2)
            {
                dataSet.ReadXml(name);
                dtGridViewImportacao.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[9];
            }


            try
            {
                prgsbarImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                    prgsbarImportacaoXML.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
                }));

                prgsbarImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                    prgsbarImportacaoXML.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 5;
                }));

                lblStatus.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "     Lendo arquivos XML individualmente...";
                }));


            }
            catch (Exception exImportarArqXML)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Não foi possível realizar a importação do conteúdo do arquivo XML e salvá-lo. Certifique-se de que o mesmo possui uma estrutura correta e válida para um XML de compra. A aplicação está sendo encerrada. Certifique-se de que o arquivo selecionado remete-se a um XML associado a uma Nota Fiscal de COMPRA!\n\n" + exImportarArqXML.Message, "ERRO!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                this.Close();
            }



        }
        catch (Exception exLeituraXML)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Erro ao realizar a leitura individual dos arquivos XML obtidos!\n\n" + exLeituraXML.Message, "ERRO!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            Close();
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém no `button2`, ao remover algumas colunas que não necessito, ocorre o seguinte erro:

> 'InvalidArgument=Value '1' não é um valor válido para 'index'.
>   Arg_ParamName_Name'

na seguinte parte do código:

```
 this.Invoke(new Action(() => lblStatus.Text = "  Reorganizando colunas desnecessárias para leitura..."));

        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns.RemoveAt(1); //ERRO AQUI
        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns.RemoveAt(2); //ERRO AQUI


        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            try
            {

                dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns.Remove("CFOP");

            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {

            }


            catch (Exception exCPROD)
            {

            }
        }));


        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            try
            {

                dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns.Remove("uCom");

            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {

            }


            catch (Exception exCPROD)
            {

            }
        }));


        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            try
            {

                dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns.Remove("qCom");

            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {

            }


            catch (Exception exCPROD)
            {

            }
        }));

        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            try
            {

                dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns.Remove("vUnCom");

            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {

            }


            catch (Exception exCPROD)
            {
            }
        }));


        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            try
            {

                dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns.Remove("vProd");


            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {

            }


            catch (Exception exCPROD)
            {

            }
        }));

        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            try
            {

                dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns.Remove("cEANTrib");

            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {

            }


            catch (Exception exCPROD)
            {

            }
        }));


        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            try
            {

                dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns.Remove("uTrib");

            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {

            }


            catch (Exception exCPROD)
            {

            }
        }));

        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            try
            {

                dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns.Remove("qTrib");

            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {

            }


            catch (Exception exCPROD)
            {

            }
        }));

        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            try
            {

                dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns.Remove("vUnTrib");

            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {

            }


            catch (Exception exCPROD)
            {

            }
        }));


        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            try
            {

                dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns.Remove("vDesc");

            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {

            }


            catch (Exception exCPROD)
            {

            }
        }));


        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            try
            {

                dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns.Remove("indTot");

            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {

            }


            catch (Exception exCPROD)
            {

            }
        }));


        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            try
            {

                dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns.Remove("CEST");

            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {

            }


            catch (Exception exCPROD)
            {

            }
        }));

        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            try
            {

                dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns.Remove("indEscala");

            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {

            }


            catch (Exception exCPROD)
            {

            }
        }));

        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {

            try
            {
                dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns.Remove("xPed");

            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {

            }

            catch (Exception exCPROD)
            {

            }

        }));

        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            try
            {

                dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns.Remove("nFCI");

            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {

            }


            catch (Exception exCPROD)
            {

            }
        }));




        //lblStatus.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        //{
        //    lblStatus.Text = "     Renomeando colunas necessárias para leitura...";
        //}));

        //dtGridViewImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        //{
        //    try
        //    {
        //        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Cód. Barras";
        //    }
        //    catch (Exception exCodBarras)
        //    {

        //        MessageBox.Show("Não foi possível encontrar a coluna referente ao Código de Barras do(s) produto(s). A aplicação está sendo encerrada. Certifique-se de que o arquivo selecionado remete-se a um XML associado a uma Nota Fiscal de COMPRA!\n\n" + exCodBarras.Message, "ERRO!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        //        Application.Exit();
        //    }

        //}));

        //dtGridViewImportacaoXML.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        //{
        //    try
        //    {
        //        dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Columns[1].HeaderText = "NCM's";
        //    }
        //    catch (Exception exNCM)
        //    {

        //        MessageBox.Show("Não foi possível encontrar a coluna referente ao NCM do(s) produto(s). A aplicação está sendo encerrada. Certifique-se de que o arquivo selecionado remete-se a um XML associado a uma Nota Fiscal de COMPRA!\n\n" + exNCM.Message, "ERRO!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        //        Application.Exit();
        //    }

        //}));
```

Parece ser como se não houvessem as colunas.

Então no meu `button3`, que seria a exportação dos registros para um arquivo de texto, também não acontece nada. Mesmo existindo os registros no datagrid, nada é exportado.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"DataBase\db.txt", true))
            {

                try
                {
                    file.WriteLine(dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "," + dtGridViewImportacaoXML.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());

                }
                catch (Exception exLerLinha)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Não foi possível realizar a leitura individual das linhas do arquivo XML. Certifique-se de que o mesmo possui uma estrutura correta e válida para um XML de compra. A aplicação está sendo encerrada. Certifique-se de que o arquivo selecionado remete-se a um XML associado a uma Nota Fiscal de COMPRA!\n\n" + exLerLinha.Message, "ERRO!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    this.Close();
                }


            }

        }
```

O curioso é que eu utilizei os seguintes `MessageBox` nos eventos `Click's` de cada `button` para verificar a quantidade de registros e colunas, ambos aparecem valores maiores que zero.

```
MessageBox.Show(dtGridViewImportacao.Rows.Count.ToString()); // QUANTIDADE DE REGISTROS É MAIOR QUE 0

 MessageBox.Show(dtGridViewImportacao.Columns.Count.ToString()); // QUANTIDADE DE COLUNAR É MAIOR QUE 0
```

Alguém saberia me dizer onde estou errando, por gentileza? Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos!

Comment: Você deve entende que o primeiro item é 0 e não 1.

Comment: Com o valor 0 também ocorre o mesmo problema. Já havia testado. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument=Value '0' não é um valor válido para 'index'.
Arg_ParamName_Name'

Comment: A tabela tem 19 colunas, em teoria iniciando por 0 ou 1 deveria funcionar, não?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que a forma mais fácil, e se calhar evitando o erro, será alterar o `DataTable` associado à `DataGridView` e depois fazer a atribuição de novo:

```
DataTable dt = dtGridViewImportacaoXML.DataSource as DataTable;

dt?.Columns.Remove("Column1");
dt?.Columns.Remove("Column2");

dtGridViewImportacaoXML.DataSource = dt;
```

As colunas terão de ser removidas por nome e não por índice, o que até é mais "seguro", visto que o índice da coluna pode variar (talvez neste caso não, mas existe essa possibilidade).